# Infinitely Nested radicals and solutions

Tags: geometry, nested-radicals

We know solution to infinite nested radicals such as $\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+...}}} = 2$

But when we subtract this infinite nested radical from 2 and again sqrt it, it is not zero.

To quote example, in one form of Viète formula for $$\pi = \lim_{n\to\infty} 2^n\cdot\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+... (\text{n - 1 times})}}}$$
[https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viète%27s_formula](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vi%C3%A8te%27s_formula)

Geometrically this is square inscribed in in unit circle, with many iterations of doubling the number of polygons. $2^n$ represents the number of polygons and **infinite nested square roots of 2** represents side of the single polygon which is very small.

My question is when we have infinite nested radicals with such solutions when we do some extra operation(s) over that(like subtraction), does the result always change? If it changes what is the proof of theorem?

Answer (score 0):

It means $a_{n+1}=\sqrt{2+a_n},$ where $a_1=\sqrt2$ and now we can calculate $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow+\infty}a_n,$ which is definitely.

Comment: To understand much better $sqrt(2+sqrt (2+sqrt(2+...$infinity$)$ gives the result as 2 as proven by its quadratic equation.

Comment: @Sivakumar Krishnamoorthi No, it's not enough. We need to prove before that it converges.

Comment: To understand much better $sqrt(2+sqrt (2+sqrt(2+...$infinity$)$ gives the result as 2 as proven by its quadratic equation. Similarly $sqrt(2-sqrt (2-sqrt(2-...$infinity$)$ gives the result 1 quadratically. But if we do single different operation extra to the infinite nested radicals, like single subtraction in above radical (which normally converges into a positive real number), the result changes and result is infinitismal number approaching zero

Comment: @Sivakumar Krishnamoorthi We can not say about quadratic equation if we did nod prove before that our sequence converges. OK. I'll try to explain by another way. Write please this quadratic equation.